# Modify VB property template in VS2008

Tags: vb.net, templates, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

In VS2008 (VB.NET) when you type Public Property X As SomeType
and press enter, VS auto-generates the rest of that property definition for you.

I would like to be able to customize what VS generates.

Any thoughts on how to go about that?  VS must have a template for it somewhere, eh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the Property generation uses an inbuilt macro. I haven't found it in the list of sample macros provided with VS. However, you can edit the `DefineAProperty.snippet`* file to modify it as per your requirement. Personally, though, I would suggest creating your own snippet rather than modifying the pre-installed ones.

Some links to more information/Snippet Editors:

1. [Creating and using Snippets - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx)
2. [Code snippet editor for VB 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb973770.aspx)
3. [Snippet Designer - CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/SnippetDesigner)